# Python TCP File Transmission over Client Server

Tags: python, python-2.7, tcp

I have following piece of code that is supposed to send the files to Client based on the information client send to server. The client will send a app request of particular name. Server will fetch the file and send it to the client. The problem is that server sends following message:

```
Not a heartbeat
No valid Message
App request Done
Done Sending Files
```

but the client is listening to file even the server is done sending the files.

The server code is given [here](https://gist.github.com/mesarvagya/765af37bc7f97f4e62fb). The client code is given [here](https://gist.github.com/mesarvagya/b877cb61b1c4180c7186)

What am I doing wrong in my code?

Comment: I'm not good with network stuff, but I think you'll have to send the size of the file first, and make the client stop receiving after that many bytes.

Comment: How does the client know that it is done receiving the file? Remember socket.recv() is a blocking call.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by sending the total length of the file before sending the file content.
And receive the length first and read upto that lenght

Code snippet that works is below

ON server side (server.py)

```
   try:
        if data["app"]:
            print "App request Done"
            file_len =  os.stat("test_app.dll").st_size
            print data["app"]
            first_flag = True
            with open("test_app.dll", "rb") as ff:
                l = ff.read(2000)
                while(l):
                    if first_flag:
                        conn.send("test_app"+"#"+str(file_len)+"#"+l)
                        first_flag = False
                    else:
                        conn.send(l)
                    l = ff.read(2000)

            print "Done Sending Files"
    except Exception, e:
        print "Not a APP Request:",  e
```

On client side :

```
while True:
    print "Sending App Request"
    s.sendall("{'app':'windows_process_monitor', 'platform':'windows'}")
    print "Receiving Files"

    first_flag = True
    with open("windows_process_monitor.dll", "wb") as dd:
        app_len = 0
        remaining_part_len = 0

        while(True):
            data = s.recv(1024)
            print data
            if not data:
                break
            if first_flag:
                app_name, app_len_str, first_part_content = data.split("#", 2)
                app_len += int(app_len_str)
                remaining_part_len += app_len
                first_received_len = len(first_part_content)
                dd.write(first_part_content)
                first_flag = False
                if app_len <= first_received_len:
                    print "all received"
                    break
                remaining_part_len -= first_received_len
            else:
                dd.write(data)
                remaining_part_len -= 1024
            if remaining_part_len <= 0:
                break
            print "inside while"

    print "Received ", repr(data)
    break
```

Comment: You must remove the {success:false} in invalid msg return type.